# How to use before circle for text in tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

How to use `::before` circle for text in tailwind?

I have a text:

[image]

How to set red circle as `::before` with padding?

Comment: You can not do that with tailwind' classes. Read [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content) article. But if you want you can add custom class to your main.css.

```
@layer components {
  .card::before {
     content: '';
  }
}
```

In your html 

```
<div class="card">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but take a look [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/GoESCHjM9e)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class='h-screen w-screen p-4'>

  <h1 class='before:inline-block before:w-3 before:h-3 before:mr-4
           before:bg-red-500 before:rounded-full '>Hello</h1>
  <div class="h-[400px]  bg-red-400 w-[5px] ml-[3.5px] "></div>

</div>
```

Comment: What if width of line is changed how auto calculate center of line with circle by vertical?

Comment: @Mamkad I'm not sure if that's possible, coz why would you change the width of the line manually and if you must do then change the `mr` value of the `before` too.